# Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)' after Pod Install

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

After adding Firebase/Firestore to my pod file and running pod install my app reports 4 Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)' messages in my code below at: let monToFri, let sat, let latitude and let longitude. How can this be corrected?

```
 func displayAnnotations() {
        
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
            
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("Postbox").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                
                let monToFri = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Monday to Friday Collection Time"] as! String?
                let sat = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Saturday Collection Time"] as! String?
                let latitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Latitude"] as! String?
                let longitude = (snapshot.value as AnyObject?)!["Longitude"] as! String?
                
                let lastCollection = "Mon - Fri: \(monToFri!)" + " Sat:  \(sat!)"
                
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Double(latitude!))!, longitude: (Double(longitude!))!)
                annotation.title = "Last Collection:"
                annotation.subtitle = lastCollection
                
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                
                self.allAnnotations.append(annotation)
                self.allIds.append(snapshot.key)
                self.postboxesLoggedLabel.text = String(self.mapView.annotations.count)
                
            })
        } else {
            
            print("Internet Connection not Available!")
            
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            // Create the actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("OK Pressed")
            }
            
            // Add the actions
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            
            // Present the controller
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why subscript snapshot.value every time it's used?

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("Postbox").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
       let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       let monToFri = data!["Monday to Friday Collection Time"] as? String ?? "Empty String" 

      // Other code....
}
```